# Read a fixed amount of characters using fgets in C

Tags: c, stdin, fgets

I'm trying to use the function fgets() in C to read 8 characters, and has to be 8 characters from stdin.

So far, I've got this

```
    char HEX[9];
    while (fgets(HEX, 8, stdin) != NULL)
    {
      if (HEX[8] == '\0')
      {
        printf("GOOD\n");
        break;
      }
      else
      {
        printf("Not 8 characters");
      }
    }
```

But it's not working. Any ideas? Also tried using if (strlen(HEX) > 8) but neither.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What happens and why do you say its not working?

Comment: fread is maybe an option?

Comment: I believe it's HEX[9] that should be '\0', and not HEX[8], right?

Comment: Arrays start at index 0, but get initialized with the actual size, meaning the last value is size-1 = 8 in this case

Comment: Oh, my bad. I believe I had too much coffee today.

Comment: @Streppel No [8] is right, [9] would be out of bounds. Remember it's 0 indexed [0..8].

Answer (score 3):

From the man pages:

> fgets() reads in at most one less than size characters from stream and stores them into the buffer pointed to by s. Reading stops after an EOF or a newline. If a newline is read, it is stored into the buffer. A terminating null byte (aq\0aq) is stored after the last character in the buffer.

You are only reading seven characters.

Answer (score 1):

One reason why this might not work is because you may be reading fewer characters than eight. Say, the user enters three characters, and presses `[Enter]`. In that case the `char` at position `8` will remain unassigned, so reading it would be undefined behavior.

What you really want to ask is whether or not the eight characters preceding the first `'\0'` in the string are all non-zero. You can do that by calling `strlen`.

Note that you cannot get a string of length eight when you pass `8` for the length, because `fgets` will use the last position for `'\0'`:

```
char HEX[9];
while (fgets(HEX, 9, stdin) != NULL)
{ //              ^--- Pass 9, not 8
  if (strlen(HEX) == 8)
  {
    printf("GOOD\n");
    break;
  }
  else
  {
    printf("Not 8 characters");
  }
}
```

Comment: The problem I'm having with strlen, is that even when I input more than 8-20 characters, it only returns a 7 tops.

Comment: @Skynight That's because you're passing `8` to `fgets` for the length, not `9`. I edited the answer to explain why.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight please use `sizeof HEX` instead of a hard-coded length. (I know you know it, just let us show OP sample code with some good practice in it. :)

Answer (score 0):

this is why:

fgets() reads in at most one less than size characters from stream and stores them into the buffer pointed to by s. Reading stops after an EOF or a newline. If a newline is read, it is stored into the buffer. A terminating null byte (aq\0aq) is stored after the last character in the buffer.

That means if you want to read 8, you will actually only read 7.  You want to read 9, have a buffer of size 9, and check to see if any of the values are null starting at the end.

```
 char HEX[10];
 memset(hex, 1, 10); //Will stop false positives since memory might be null to begin with
while (fgets(HEX, 9, stdin) != NULL)
{
  if (HEX[9] == '\0')
  {
    printf("GOOD\n");
    break;
  }
  else
  {
    printf("Not 8 characters");
  }
}
```

Comment: Yes, but read the definition: it stores a null byte AFTER reading min(sizeofstr, 8).

Comment: and hex[8] is the ninth element in the array

Comment: `char HEX[9]` would be sufficient.  and it should be `HEX[8] == '\0'`.

Answer (score 0):

If you only want to read 8 characters from standard input, the function fgetc() may serve your purposes better.

Consider the following code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    char str[8];
    int incre1=0;
    for (incre1=0;incre1<=7;incre1++) {
        str[incre1] = fgetc(stdin);
        if(str[incre1] == EOF) {
            printf("less than 8 characters\n");
            break; }
    }
printf("%s\n",str);
return(0);
}
```

This code will read the first 8 characters from standard input (including newlines), either from the console or from piped output of another program, and place them into the `str` buffer. By adding a check in the middle of the `for` loop for an End-of-FILE character, you can make your program respond accordingly should the input consist of less than 8 characters.

Note that if you are trying to code a program with interactive console input, you can also include an appropriate `break` condition should a newline character be read.

Answer (score 0):

fgets() store a \n on the 8th position in your case.

So , You have two options,

1. Check for \0 at 9th position.
2. Replace \n on the 8th position with \0 then check for \0 on the 8th position.